# IMAP append message

Tags: c#, imap, gmail-imap

I'm looking for an IMAP4 library for .NET (preferably working on Mono out of the box) which can Create new messages in mailbox, returns the ID of this new message allowing later to delete the message by that ID. None of the ones I tried (Lumisoft, AE.Net.Mail, ImapX) can do this simple stuff. Is there any full-featured IMAP4 implementation for .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mail.dll IMAP library](http://www.limilabs.com/mail).

It supports UIDPLUS:

```
long? uid = imap.UploadMessage("[Gmail]/Sent Mail", email);

imap.DeleteMessageByUID((long)uid);
```

Please note that this is a commercial product I created.

Comment: Thanks, but I finally got away from storing data in IMAP enabled mailbox. The protocol is just too bad and handles message updates terribly ineffectively. I will be doing my own webservice instead.

Answer (score -1):

Full featured ... i doubt there is any IMAP client/server what supports ALL IMAP extentions. You are talking about UIDPLUS extention. With lumisoft you can do that, but need to use StoreMessageAsync method, it will allow you to access full server final response(StoreMessageAsyncOP.FinalResponse), it easy to parse UID out of it.
Though normal synchronous StoreMessage won't support it at moment.
With ManualResetEvent it's easy to turn asynchronous method to synchronous.